# Is it possible to put a form control on its own thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance

I'm using a DataGridView and some operations that I do cause it to become unresponsive for periods of time.  Normally I would put data processing in its own thread to make the form more responsive, but in this case it's the DataGridView itself that's taking so long.

This leads me to wonder whether it's possible to have the main form on one thread and the DataGridView on another thread so it doesn't prevent the main form from responding.

I completely understand that doing so is probably not 'safe' and likely opens up a can of worms that makes it hardly worth trying and I fully expect this post will be getting down votes for merely suggesting such a ridiculous idea.

Is this possible?  And if so how would you go about it?

EDIT: I figured out how to fix the problem at hand.  The short answer was to use a flag when setting the RowCount so CellValueNeeded() can bail out immediately.  There's really more to the story and I had already been doing this partially, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no, because the control needs to interact with other controls (or at least the window), and they all need to be on the same thread.

Doing so seems to imply that you're doing processing on the UI thread, which itself is also a big no-no. You should run all of your *major processes* on their own thread, and then save the *final presentation* for the UI thread -- work on one thread, screen updates on another.

Comment: Right, I mentioned in the post that the part that's taking so long is the DGV itself (specifically when I reset the RowCount).  I *can't* offset that.  Well, technically I've tried but when it resets the RowCount twice in a row the second attempt just waits on the first one (becuase of Invoke()) so it ends up locking the form up anyway.

Comment: Update your question and include the code that causes the slowness. Don't fall in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), instead of asking how to do your soultion to the problem (DGV on another thread) ask about how to fix your DGV so it does not become unresponsive in the firstplace.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to have multiple UI threads in a given application.  However it is not possible to compose UI components from different threads onto the same Form.  For a given form all of the components must be on the same thread

The best way to fix this problem is to move the data processing itself onto a separate thread.  Only do the absolute minimum to update the UI from the UI thread.  That should help with the responsiveness

Comment: I can't offload processing as explained in post and expounded upon in my comment on sircodesalot's answer. :/

Comment: @BVernon In most cases you really can.  For example, you may be deferring processing of the underlying data source, which results in you spending time doing non-UI work in the UI thread.

Comment: Deferred operations not the problem here... just that it was calling for 'every' cell value when the RowCount was changed which takes a while when there are a lot of rows.  I actually thought I had the CellValueNeeded returning immediately during this process instead of retrieving values but I was mistaken.

Comment: @JaredPar My current solution is to use a flag that lets CellValueNeeded return immediately when the RowCount is being changed... but I have to manually set the flag and RowCount.  I would prefer to let this be handled through a ListChanged event so it's automatic.  However, when RowCount is set through the ListChange event within the DGV derived control it actually never calls CellValueNeeded but it still takes forever... and I have no idea what it's doing because it doesn't hit breakpoints in any of my other methods.  If that makes sense, I'd welcome any thoughts you have on how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

take a look into use of virtualization in the grid.

And please give code sample to what operation is taking too long!

Comment: Already using virtualization.  The DGV is lightening fast if I don't ever reset the RowCount... which has been my solution so far (just to leave blank rows at the bottom) but I'm trying to see if I can fix that without hurting performance.

Comment: @BVernon have you tried to [set RowCount = 0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c823a522-56f5-451b-9d5e-bdeac8833eeb/speeding-up-setting-of-datagridviewrowcount) before you set the new value?

Answer (score 0):

No, but from events fired from the dataGridView you could send a worker to perform async tasks and then update the dataGridView using the controls Invoke method from the worker thread

Comment: Tried that... problem being that when you do a couple Invoke's in a row they wait for the previous one to finish processing so it defeats the purpose.